# Not able to retrieve value in JSON response

Tags: json, automated-tests, robotframework

I am working on API response validation. I am trying to get the value of the particular field in the API response for validation.

This is my API response.

```
{
    "currentdatetime": "11",
    "syncinterval_seconds": 4,
    "public_keys": [
        {
            "system": "aa",
            "pubkey": "aa"
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "username": "user",
            "user_id": "user",
            "realname": "user_10",
            "emailaddress": "test@gmail.com",
            "accountenabled": false,
            "mustchangepassword": false,
            "passwordhash": "$E6gi",
            "accesslevel": [
                "WORKER"
            ],
            "expiration": "2022-11-02T16:21:52",
            "site_specific": false,
            "symkey": "aaaa",
            "privatekey": "aaa"
        },
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get username /user id from users through robot code.Like this

```
 ${response}=     GET     ${Base_URL}/v1/sync/users    ${data}   headers=${header}
 ${origin}=       Get Json Value From String   ${response.content}  users
 ${lines} =       Set Variable  ${origin.content['users']['username']}
```

It is throwing a "type" error.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like 'users' contains a list and it is not included in your code. You can try this quick fix: `${origin.content['users'][0]['username']}`

Comment: I am getting this error - Resolving variable '${response.content['users'][0]['username']}' failed: TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What does `Get Json Value From String` do. Based on it's name, I would assume it works similarly to JSONLibrary `Convert String To Json`. If this is case, you should be able to refer to JSON with `${origin['users'][0]['username']}`